# Struggling with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I've been struggling to transform an XML document. I've done the w3schools tutorial but everything I have tried has failed in one way or another.
Basically I'm trying to transform this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Report Title="Nodes">
<Record NodeID="123" NodeName="TESTNode1" IP_Address="251.300.000.001" />
</Report>
```

Into this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Report Title="Nodes">
<Record>
<NodeID>123</NodeID>
<NodeName>TestNode1</NodeName>
<IP_Address>251.300.000.001</IP_Address>
</Record>
</Report>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us some of your attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stylesheet will do the transform for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="Record">
    <Record>
      <NodeID><xsl:value-of select="@NodeID"/></NodeID>
      <NodeName><xsl:value-of select="@NodeName"/></NodeName>
      <IP_Address><xsl:value-of select="@IP_Address"/></IP_Address>
    </Record>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/Report">
    <Report>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@Title"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Record"/>
    </Report>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Will thanks - I can use this to further my understanding. I couldn't apply what I thought I understood. The problem I couldn't get round was the various values stored in a single child element (Record).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use more generic template based on [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|/node()/@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In this case it is not necessary to enumerate all attributes/elements. On the otherside - as @JLRishe noted - there is no guarantee of the order of elements created from attributes.

Comment: It would be much cleaner to use `Report/@*` instead of `@*[name(parent::node()) = 'Report']`. Another thing to note here is that this provides no guarantees on the order of the `NodeID`, `NodeName`, and `IP_Address` elements.

Comment: You're right thank you for your comment. `/node()/@*` might be even better - it should preserve attributes of root element regardless its name.

Comment: I tell my students to use /*/@* since an XML document has exactly one document element and no other kind of node has attributes.